# What is wrong with this 'Upload media to Dropbox' answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-answer

So, I failed a review audit (for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12877940) post), and I'm not exactly sure why. Before I click `I understand`, I'd like to actually understand. ;-) I assume the post must have been flagged as spam, but several of the other answers to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17793297/712526) are in the same vein.

Personally, I think that question invited rather low quality answers, but dances on the line of okayish. And if the question is worthy, then this answer ought to be, also: but then, what am I missing?

I'm not familiar with WordPress, so I can't tell whether the plugin here matches the OP's request, but it seems at least related.

Thanks!

[image: Low Quality Post Review audit]

Comment: [It's always okay to click the Skip button](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/215552) if you're not sure, or you're not familiar with the technology.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan When I skip *spammy* audit posts, the system warns me saying I should be more careful so I am not sure if it's always okay.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan For reviewing code edits, I heartily agree. But in the low quality queue, I generally review for clarity and a genuine attempt to be useful, figuring that voting will sort out whether it's actually useful. In this specific case, it looks like the real problem was not visible in the the post itself, but in a missing disclaimer of affiliation.

Comment: Good points @ayhan and jpaugh. "Always" was perhaps hyperbolic, even with the caveats on the end.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for your comments. I'm making a concerted effort to (re)understand the community guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post is technically spam, as the poster did not disclose their affiliation with the product they are promoting.

**From [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion):**

> The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.

That last sentence is key, and from [their profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3552278/aelbuni) we can see they did not follow it.

> [image: profile info]

However it appears they were given the benefit of the doubt, and rather than being marked as spam and given the rep penalty, it was just deleted instead.

As for the other answers, they were probably given a pass for being much older. That question really should be closed though, as it is a software recommendations question.

Comment: Yes, all you have to do to legitimize your [otherwise-inappropriate answer is include an irrelevant apologia](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14784624/).